# paypal sha256 related CURL issue

Tags: php, paypal, ssl

To test the SHA256 compatibility for paypal - in my linux web server I tried the below and got this error. I do have the SHA256 SSL certificates installed though.

curl https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp

ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0

Any help welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you like totest paypal ssl connections, use proper options:

```
curl -I -v https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp
```

or script like this one:
https://github.com/magenx/Magento-Automated-Server-Configuration-from-MagenX/blob/master/tmp/tlstest.php